# Function not running, no error on firefox

Tags: javascript, html

So, I'm working on a random sentence generator. I'm trying to get it to work, but the function does not seem to be running (this is saved as an html file and I'm running it in firefox). Here's the code so far:

```html
<html>

<body>
  <h1>Hello.</h1>
  <br>
  <p>This is a website made by me. No, I do not own a domain. However, you can run this file from your computer. Thanks for looking at my website. Please enjoy!</p>
  Hey! look at this button I made! I'm working on more stuff as you look at this.
  <button onclick="GenerateSentence()">Click me for a random sentence!</button>
  <p id="Output"></p>
  <script>
    function GenerateSentence() {
      alert("test")
      var subjectran = math.floor(math.random() * subject.length)
      var verbran = math.floor(math.random() * verb.length)
      var adjectiveran = math.floor(math.random() * adjective.length)
      var objectran = math.floor(math.random() * object.length)
      var adverbran = math.floor(math.random() * adverb.length)
      var subject = ["Perry", "Obama", "Liam", "Eric", "Gregory", "Daniel", "Mikey", "Pog", "Benji", "Raj", "Jarec", "Theo", "Zach", "Nicholas", "Samir", "Ivan", "Colonel Sanders", "SK"]
      var verb = ["eats", "hates", "loves", "dyes", "kills", "dreams about", "runs with", "deep-fries", "fries", "burns", "ignites", "texts", "harvests", "stores", "runs over", "buys", "sells", "explodes", "studies", "destroys", "breaks", "reks", "bodies", "mauls", "melts", "pops", "slices", "butchers", "has nightmares about", "has flashbacks about", "jars", "thinks about", "makes art with", "builds a house with", "writes with"]
      var adjective = ["dank", "red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violet", "purple", "white", "black", "brown", "red-orange", "yellow-green", "dumb", "stupid", "smart", "", "rainbow", "titanium", "adamantium", "paper", "black and white", "sad", "happy", "angry", "flat", "winded", "donated", "edible", "fat", "slow", "fast", "energetic", "lazy", "hot", "cold", "dead"]
      var object = ["toys", "cars", "Ferraris", "Mustangs", "Maseraties", "buses", "people", "heads", "blocks", "houses", "cheeses", "Teletubbies", "Gengis Kahns", "mustaches", "cows", "pigs", "chickens", "houses", "Nicholas Cages", "George Washingtons", "Kim Jong Uns", "calculators", "tables", "schools", "classes", "suits", "pencils", "fried chicken", "sheep", "moose", "sinks", "beans", "tomatoes", "peas", "pumpkins", "tater tots", "hotdogs", "lemons"]
      var adverb = ["", "quickly", "often", "slowly", "carefully", "correctly", "eagerly", "easily", "fast", "loudly", "quietly", "patiently", "outside", "somewhere", "downstairs", "abroad", "underground", "upstairs", "anywhere", "accidentally", "intentionally", "seldom", "sometimes", "usually", "rarely", "here"]
      ver sentence = (subject[subjectran] + " " + verb[verbran] + " " + adjective[adjectiveran] + " " + object[objectran] + " " + adverb[adverbran])
      document.getElementById("Output").innerHTML = sentence
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The snippet says the error "missing ; before statement", but I do not get any errors when running in firefox. Remember, I'm kind of an amateur. Did I make a mistake, or is this supposed to work? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** after looking at the 3 comments, I saw mistakes i hadn't noticed as I looked over. Also, I was unaware the arrays weren't working for that reason. Thanks for helping!

Comment: You've got `ver` instead of `var`. Also it's `Math` not `math`. And you're trying to access the lengths of your arrays before you create them, move the declarations+initialisations to the front.

Comment: 1. `ver sentence`. You mean `var sentence`. 2. You count indexes before arrays initialized, so - all xxx.length are undefined. 3. `math` is not `Math`

Comment: And it's `Math`, not `math`. JavaScript is case-sensitive

Answer (score 0):

Here's the HTML with all corrections:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Hello.</h1><br>
<p>This is a website made by me. No, I do not own a domain. However, you can run this file from your computer. Thanks for looking at my website. Please enjoy!</p>
Hey! look at this button I made! I'm working on more stuff as you look at this.<button onclick="generateSentence();">Click me for a random sentence!</button>
<p id="Output"></p>
<script>
function generateSentence(){
    alert("test");
    var subject = ["Perry","Obama","Liam","Eric","Gregory","Daniel","Mikey","Pog","Benji","Raj","Jarec","Theo","Zach","Nicholas","Samir","Ivan","Colonel Sanders","SK"];
    var verb = ["eats","hates","loves","dyes","kills","dreams about","runs with","deep-fries","fries","burns","ignites","texts","harvests","stores","runs over","buys","sells","explodes","studies","destroys","breaks","reks","bodies","mauls","melts","pops","slices","butchers","has nightmares about","has flashbacks about","jars","thinks about","makes art with","builds a house with","writes with"];
    var adjective = ["dank","red","orange","yellow","green","blue","indigo","violet","purple","white","black","brown","red-orange","yellow-green","dumb","stupid","smart","","rainbow","titanium","adamantium","paper","black and white","sad","happy","angry","flat","winded","donated","edible","fat","slow","fast","energetic","lazy","hot","cold","dead"];
    var object = ["toys","cars","Ferraris","Mustangs","Maseraties","buses","people","heads","blocks","houses","cheeses","Teletubbies","Gengis Kahns","mustaches","cows","pigs","chickens","houses","Nicholas Cages","George Washingtons","Kim Jong Uns","calculators","tables","schools","classes","suits","pencils","fried chicken","sheep","moose","sinks","beans","tomatoes","peas","pumpkins","tater tots","hotdogs","lemons"];
    var adverb = ["","quickly","often","slowly","carefully","correctly","eagerly","easily","fast","loudly","quietly","patiently","outside","somewhere","downstairs","abroad","underground","upstairs","anywhere","accidentally","intentionally","seldom","sometimes","usually","rarely","here"];

    var subjectran = Math.floor(Math.random()*subject.length);
    var verbran = Math.floor(Math.random()*verb.length);
    var adjectiveran = Math.floor(Math.random()*adjective.length);
    var objectran = Math.floor(Math.random()*object.length);
    var adverbran = Math.floor(Math.random()*adverb.length);
    var sentence = (subject[subjectran] + " " + verb[verbran] + " " + adjective[adjectiveran] + " " + object[objectran] + " " + adverb[adverbran]);
    document.getElementById("Output").innerHTML = sentence;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

- Amended ver to var.
- Added some semicolons.
- Renamed math to Math.
- Put arrays before other code that require them.

You should also consider moving those arrays outside of the function so that you don't keep initializing them.